# Xcode iOS: How to communicate with other Controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, events, communication

I have the following issue and need a patter to solve it:

To make it simple I have two views, the MasterViewController and the PreferencesController, the last one is an popup from the first. The PrefController has delegated some methods to the MasterController.

But now I wanna catch a Popover-Event from the PreferencesController and inform the MasterController about it.

What is the best way to do it? I don't wanna use a delegate in the other direction now too, that doenst seem to be a good solution. I thought about creating an event for this, but you might have a better advice/solution for this situation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something in your structure doesn't really make sense - why is the PreferencesController a delegate for MasterController if the PreferencesController is a popup? I would expect the popup to have a delegate property in order to pass back information to the master controller, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out the [NSNotificationCenter reference guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) maybe this can do the job? It's perfect for communication between controllers and the best thing is they don't have to know about each other. Else you may have to declare a protocol for passing the data between the contorllers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just implemented the NSNotifacationCenter but now I have the following small issue:
My MasterController implements the class method "+ (void)YourSelector:(NSNotification *)notification". But since it is a class method I can't call an instance method nor any variables in this method. But without this, the whole method doenst make any sense of course.
Could you also tell me, how to manage it that I can use my instance methods/variables of MasterControl?

Comment: First, like @Stavash sais, if your PreferencesController is a delegate for MasterController, this seems a bit strange. Making it the opposite way won't take you so long and it will be a more natural way of communication between the viewcontrollers. I think this will give you a better understanding of it all. You want PreferencesController to be a subview of your MasterController so it's delegate is locaded in MasterController and you can communicate with the delegate from PreferencesController.

Comment: Later if you want data from the MasterController to PreferencesController this can just be passed through delegate too.

Comment: Thanks, the delegate was the better choice :-)